# Get uncompressed size of the dataset on HDFS after being read by Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to improve the performance of my Spark application. To this end, I am trying to determine the optimal number of shuffle partitions for a dataset. I read from multiple sources that each partition should be about 128 MB.

So, if I have a 1GB file, I'll need around 8 partitions. But my question is how do I find the file size? I know I can find the file size on the hdfs using the following

```
hdfs dfs -du -s {data_path}
```

But from what I understand this is the compressed size and the actual size of the file is different. (Spark uses a compression codec while writing parquet files, by default `snappy`). And this leads me to two questions actually

1. How do I find the actual uncompressed size of the file?
2. What should the number of shuffle partitions be based on- compressed size or actual size?

Comment: Did you mean de serialized data size? Uncompressed is easy, just uncompress the file and you get the result.

Comment: @Clock Slave were you able to get the uncompressed size of a file without uncompressing it ?

Answer (score 1):

Shuffle partitions are independent of the data size.
The data is uncompressed and then shuffled based on the number of shuffle partitions(using hash partitioner, range partitioner, etc).
Generally, the shuffle partitions are tuned
1. To increase the parallelism available in reducer stage.
2. To reduce the amount of data processed by shuffle partition(if we observe spills or it the reduce stage is memory intensive)

> I read from multiple sources that each partition should be about 128 MB.

This is applicable only to mapper stages. The split sizes in the mapper are computed based on the size of compressed data. You can tune the size of the mapper splits using `spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes`

And the shuffle partitions(configured using `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions`, defaulting to 200) is related to reducer stages.

In short, compression comes into play only in mapper stages and not reducer stages.